# Header is not allowed as both an origin custom header and a forward header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create a new origin in an existing Cloudfront distribution that will point to an S3 bucket. One of the other origins of the distribution is pointing to a service and it has a custom header that is forwarding to the service to verify that the request is coming from Cloudfront. The problem is that when I try to create new origin, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Any idea what maybe the source of the problem?

Comment: Can you paste also your Origin Request Policy? I think you has duplicated that Header in both Origin Request Policy and Custom Header in the Origin itself

Comment: @ChuongNguyen I see the header as part of the default behaviour in Origin request settings, request policy

Comment: Yeah, so maybe it is default, and then you added it in another place so it causes conflict.

Comment: @ChuongNguyen but on the new origin I am not trying to add the header, it is one one of the origins already and it is on the origin request policy.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Cause I also have a distribution with multiple Origins, both S3 and ALB. Is it a Custom header? Oh, can you try use the default Origin Request policy?